# Cannot invoke "javax.servlet.http.Part.getInputStream()" because "imgPart" is null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

estoy trabajando en mi proyecto de Java Web Dinamico y no logro avanzar con lo siguiente.
Al realizar un insert de datos desde mi vista JSP a mi base de datos y estoy recibiendo el siguiente error:

```
Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error
Tipo Informe de Excepción

**mensaje Cannot invoke "javax.servlet.http.Part.getInputStream()" because "imgPart" is null**

Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.servlet.http.Part.getInputStream()" because "imgPart" is null
    ar.roberto.proyecto.controllers.AdminController.getCreateArticulos(AdminController.java:111)
    ar.roberto.proyecto.controllers.AdminController.doGet(AdminController.java:73)
    ar.roberto.proyecto.controllers.AdminController.doPost(AdminController.java:229)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de registro del servidor.
```

Este es el metodo **getCreateArticulos** que utilizo en el controlador:

```
private void getCreateArticulos(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException, SQLException {

        // Obtener los datos del formulario
        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String descripcion = request.getParameter("descripcion");
        String precioParam = request.getParameter("precio");
        BigDecimal precio = BigDecimal.ZERO; // Valor por defecto en caso de que el parámetro no esté presente o sea nulo
        if (precioParam != null && !precioParam.isEmpty()) {
            precio = new BigDecimal(precioParam);
        }
        int stock = 0; // Valor por defecto en caso de que el parámetro no esté presente o sea nulo

        String stockParam = request.getParameter("stock");
        if (stockParam != null && !stockParam.isEmpty()) {
            stock = Integer.parseInt(stockParam);
        }

        Part imgPart = request.getPart("img");

        // Convertir la imagen a un array de bytes
        InputStream is = imgPart.getInputStream();
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
        byte[] imgBytes = baos.toByteArray();

        // Crear el objeto Articulo
        Articulo articulo = new Articulo();
        articulo.setNombre(nombre);
        articulo.setDescripcion(descripcion);
        articulo.setPrecio(precio);
        articulo.setStock(stock);
        articulo.setImgBytes(imgBytes);

        // Insertar el artículo en la base de datos
        adao.insert(articulo);

        // Redirigir al usuario a la página de detalle del artículo recién creado
        response.sendRedirect("admin?accion=articulos");

    }
```

El metodo insert que utilizo en la clase **DAO**:

```
    public void insert(Articulo articulo) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;

        try {
            con = ConexionFactory.getConexion();

            stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO articulos (nombre, descripcion, precio, stock, img) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            stmt.setString(1, articulo.getNombre());
            stmt.setString(2, articulo.getDescripcion());
            stmt.setBigDecimal(3, articulo.getPrecio());
            stmt.setInt(4, articulo.getStock());
            stmt.setBytes(5, articulo.getImgBytes());

            stmt.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            // Cerrar statement y conexión en el bloque finally para asegurarse de que se cierran incluso si se produce una excepción
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Y por ultimo el formulario en el archivo JSP.

```
            <h1>Crear Artículo</h1>
    <form action="admin?accion=createArticulos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required><br><br>

        <label for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
        <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea><br><br>

        <label for="precio">Precio:</label>
        <input type="number" id="precio" name="precio" step=".01" required><br><br>

        <label for="stock">Stock:</label>
        <input type="number" id="stock" name="stock" required><br><br>

        <label for="img">Imagen:</label>
        <input type="file" id="img" name="img" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Crear">
    </form>
        <!-- modal img -->
        <div id="modal">
            <span class="cerrar-modal">&times;</span> <img id="modal-img">
        </div>
```

Parecería que toma los valores del formulario como NULL, pero ya revise y los datos deberian llegar bien al controlador.
Favor su ayuda, Saludos!

Comment: Hola Roberto, bienvenido, esta parte del mensaje **"imgPart" is null ar.roberto.proyecto.controllers.AdminController.getCreateArticulos(AdminController.java:111)**, te dice que en la linea "111" de la clase **AdminController**, la variable **imgPart** no está inicializada,  no nos mostrás la clase en cuestión, por lo que no puedo decir nada más, fijate porque esta null, y si no encontrás el problema, agregá lo que falta a tu pregunta, para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Marcelo, gracias por la bienvenida y por la ayuda.
Actualicé mi posteo con el metodo getCreateArticulos, en particular la linea 111 de la clase AdminController es en la que se indica:

Part imgPart = request.getPart("img");

Comment: Sobre qué versión de Java trabajas? Qué contenedor o servidor web usas? Sabes qué versión de servlet-api estás usando?

Comment: Estos son los datos de la version de Java que utilizo:
openjdk version "1.8.0_352"
IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition (build 1.8.0_352-b08)
OpenJ9   - e04a7f6c1
OMR      - 85a21674f
JCL      - b213334935 based on jdk8u352-b08)

Estoy corriendo el proyecto en Apache Tomcat 9.0.65

Lo que intento hacer es guardar un Producto con imagenes desde mi app web en mi base de datos, cuando realizo la misma accion pero con obtejos que no tienen imagenes funciona bien